# Wrapping JSON response in an abstracted way in PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, response, laravel-blade

I am making a REST API that will return different JSON responses depending on which type of User is making the call.

There is a single endpoint: `example.com/api/v1/collect` that uses [Laravel's API authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests) to get the User model with `$user = auth()->guard('api')->user();`.

Each `User` will belong to a `Type`.

If `User 1` (type_id 1) makes the call, the response will look like:

```
{
    "example": 1,
    "success": true,
    "data" : [
        ...
    ]
}
```

If `User 2` (type_id 2) makes the call, the response can be different, depending on the user's type. It could look like:

```
{
    "example": 2,
    "response" : [
        ...
    ],
    "custom": "string",
    "success": 200
}
```

The `...` is the data that we are sending back (for example a list of Post titles) and it will always be the same, but the "envelope" (or wrapper) around it would be specific to each user (or type of user).

So far, I've found two solutions to wrap that `...` in an abstracted way:

**Solution 1**: Using [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)

```
// Api\V1\ApiController.php

$data = $user->posts->pluck('title');

// Each type of user will have a different blade filename
// There could be around a 100 types which will result in a 100 blade files
// The filename is stored in the database
$filename = $user->type->filename; // returns 'customBladeTemplate'

// Return a JSON response after passing the $data to the view
return response()->json([
    view($filename, compact('data'))->render(),
]);
```

Using a blade file for each type of user allows me to wrap the data like this:

```
// resources/views/customBladeTemplate.blade.php
// This filename has to match the one in the database column
{
    "example": 1,
    "success": true,
    "data" : [
        {!! $data !!}
    ]
}
```

*That will output a JSON response for the User 1 (example 1)*

**Solution 2**: Using [Laravel response macros](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros)

```
// Api\V1\ApiController.php

$data = $user->posts->pluck('title');

// Each type of user will have a different macro name
// There could be around a 100 types which will result in a 100 different macros
// The macro name is stored in the database
$macroName = $user->type->macro_name; // returns 'customMacroName'

return response()->{macroName}($data);
```

Creating a Macro for each type of user, using the macro name from the DB:

```
// App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function boot()
{
    Response::macro('customMacroName', function ($data) {
        return Response::json([
            'example' => 2,
            'response' => $data,
            'custom' => 'string',
            'success' => 200,
        ]);
    });
}
```

*That macro will output a JSON response for the User 2 (example 2)*

---

Both options work fine but I am still wondering:

- **Is there another (*possibly better*) way to do it?**
- Are those two solutions valid or can they be enhanced?
- Which of those two solutions seem to be better and why?

---

**Edit:** The `$data` is not actually coming from an eloquent model, it is rather from a serialized JSON column ([JSON casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)) - which means I can't use the [Laravel API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? It seems a bit unnatural (and not very RESTfull) to provide a structure based on who requests it. Sounds like a documentation nightmare as well..

Comment: I have simplified the question for readability, but the app is actually an iPaaS (integration platform) that maps data from external APIs (ie. Magento) towards other APIs (ie. QuickBooks).

Each API having different JSON output/input and could be REST, SOAP or WebHooks. 

I have to adapt that JSON output to each one of the connectors, while trying to avoid hardcoding the payloads but rather keep it "abstracted" as much as possible. 

That is why I went for blade templating in the first place, but I agree, it is not really RESTful!

I just can't come up with any other solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) to change what the response looks like.

With middleware you could change the response after the execution of your regular code, without having to take this into account in the controller itself. Using the below code you modify the response AFTER it has been executed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        // Calls the controller and processes the request. 
        $response = $next($request); 

        // Here you can retrieve the user and modify the response however you want. 

        // Some example code: 
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->type == 1) {
           ... //Change response for user type 1
        }
        if ($user->type == 2) {
           ... //Change response for user type 2
        }
        // Etc...

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: That is a good solution here. But it doesn't cover the wrapping of the JSON response, so it would be pretty similar to the second solution: having one macro / having one `if` statement per user type.

Comment: This way you don't need to put that check in the controller though. So if at some point the system has more routes, you just add this middleware and it's done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the response formatting you should go with the `Laravel API Resources`

Based on your requirement(data formate different for two type of users), you can create two different Api Resource classes.

`AdminResource` & `UserResource`.

Here you have more flixibility on controlling fields or orgnizing data.

Here is how you can define the resource class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class UserResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

And you can use this as:

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

Route::get('/user', function () {
    return new UserResource(User::find(1));
});
```

If you would like to include with condition check in with user type, you can create a common function called `renderJson($userType, $data)` and place this in your parent class or can wrap with traits, all depends on your application architecture.

Here you can find laravel documentation for API Resource: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

**Edited:**

With **Laravel API Resource**, you not only parse the modal object, you can parse any arrayble object.

> Essentially they are just simple objects with one very important job
>   to do — transform your objects (interesting I said objects and not
>   models). To do this out of the box, all you have to do is instantiate
>   the Resource (collection or individual) with an Arrayable object. If
>   you did nothing else but generate a standard Resource and pass in an
>   Arrayable object the Resource would transform that object
>   automatically, and because Models are Arrayable this is where I got
>   caught out because if you create a resource collection and instantiate
>   it with a collection of models then the models get toArray'd and not
>   their corresponding resource.
>   Src: https://medium.com/@dinotedesco/laravel-api-resources-what-if-you-want-to-manipulate-your-models-before-transformation-8982846ad22c

So in your case if you can just `collect()` the json data and pass to api resource.

Comment: The `$data` is not actually coming from an eloquent model, it is rather from a serialized JSON column - which means I can't use the Laravel API resources. This was a good call though. I've edited the question.

Comment: @PhilMarc here you can use the API Resources to parse any Arrable ojects either it's model or any other standard objects. So I think, you can still consider this.

Comment: If the goal is to customize a root-level JSON object of the response then you wouldn't want to be customizing individual Resources. Resources are often nested and you'd end up with every level receiving the treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how different the responses are from each other.  I'm inclined to take inventory of each type's common features and build a response array as appropriate.  This could be done in the controller or a helper function and then returned using Laravel's JSON response type.

```php
$response = [];

// results common to all types
$response['example'] = $example;
$response['success'] = $success;

// customized results for specific types
if (in_array($type, [1, 3, 4, 5, ...])) {
    $response['data'] = $dotdotdot;
}
if (in_array($type, [2, 6, 7, 8, ...])) {
    $response['response'] = $dotdotdot;
    $response['custom'] = $custom;
}

return response()->json($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for. I had something similiar a few months ago and fixed it with json files. As json is amazingly fast and you can create thousands of types.

Sorry for my bad english i will fix it after the weekend :-)

Let's get started.

First the user logs in using laravel passport or api routes. 
Second the api calls a controller.(class). I will create a class based on your info.

let's say the api calls the `ApiController` and the method `handle`

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController
{


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {

        //first let's find the correct format
        $type = $requets->user()->type; //lets say type_1

        $config = $this->getUserType($type);

        //i don't know where you data comes from but let's say $data is your data.
        $data = json_encode(['some' => "data", 'to' => "return"]);

        //lets fill the data
        $response = $this->fillDataInConfig($data, $config);

        return response()->json($response);
    }

    /**
     * Find the user type config by type name
     * 
     * @param string $type
     * @return object
     */
    private function getUserType(string $type) : string
    {
        //let store them in the local storage
        $config = \Storage::disk('local')->get("api_types/$type.json");

        return json_decode($config);
    }

    /**
     * Fill the data
     * 
     * @param mixed $data
     * @param object $config
     * @return object
     */
    private function fillDataInConfig($data, object $config) : object
    {
        //as for your example. The reusl//        
//      {
//            "example": 2,
//            "response" : *responseData*, <===== where the response should be
//            "custom": "string",
//            "success": 200
//        }

        foreach($config as $index => $value){
            if($value === '*responseData*'){
                $config->{$idnex} = $data;
            }
        }
        //the data is filled in the response index

        return $config;
    }


}
```